# On form submit (html) how can i pass value of button and alert

Tags: css, form-submit

Suppose I have 10 buttons and after pressing submit I want to send the value of that button to control servlet I did like this:

In HTML-page

```
<body> 
    <form action="test" method="get">
        <input type="button"  name="dfhgdh" value="uiui"  />   
        <input type="button" value="uiui" name="dfhgdh" />
        <input type="button" value="dghdh" name="dfhgdh" />
        <input type="button" value="dthydt" name="dfhgdh" />
        <input type="submit" value="submit" name="fuyjuf" />
    </form>
</body>
```

And in Control-servlet

```
Protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String mn =request.getParameter("dfhgdh");        
    System.out.println(mn);    
}
```

Can any body tell where 'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to watchout for IE < 9 when passing parameters via a button.  These browsers will send the innerHTML of the button, instead of the value attribute.  To advert this I add Javascript on the page that adds the values from the button to a hidden input within the page.